# Deleted post background too narrow when editing

Tags: bug, edits, design, deleted-posts

When editing a deleted answer or question, the input field for the edit summary sticks out:

[image]

The background should be a little bit wider, also to provide some padding around the text area for the body. That, or the input fields should be made a little bit narrower.

<sub>(Tested in the latest Safari and Firefox on macOS Mojave, and in Chrome on Windows 10.)</sub>